# nodemon is not restarting the server when using node-java package

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon, node-java

When using **node-java** package, **nodemon doesn't restart** when the files change. If I **remove node-java** package then **nodemon will restart** when there are file changes.

Even the manual restart (rs) is not working when using node-java package in server. Following is the behavior.

[image: nodemon the behavior when using node-java] alon

**And even it throws the following:**

```js
events.js:85
     throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
           ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
   at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
   at Server._listen2 (net.js:1156:14)
   at listen (net.js:1182:10)
   at Server.listen (net.js:1267:5)
```

Since the port 4000 is being used only once in server and no where else, its behaving weird.

Comment: I created example server using `node-java` module and server restarted successfully on file change. Did you create custom nodemon.json file containing configuration?

Comment: @ezrepotein when using java.import this issue was observed. (as following)

     var java = require('java');
     var preview = java.import('com.previewer.Previewer');

Comment: Similar issue found at nodemon repo,  https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/573 there seems to no comments on it yet.

Comment: After importing class I got the same issue. Maybe try supervisor as dannyn-mirth suggested on github issue.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that node-java somehow magically 'overrides' what's happening when receiving `SIGUSR2` signal. In such a case, the `SIGUSR2` signal (used by `nodemon`) to restart the app may fail terminating the app.

(Quick) Fix:

after the node-java has screwed your `SIGUSR2` handling mechanism, add the following snippet of code:

```
process.once('SIGUSR2', function() {
  process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGUSR2')
})
```

note that you must do this AFTER the `node-java` (or something which uses it, in my case it is `node-tika`) does its 'job' (in my case, immediately after requiring `node-tika`).

To be honest, I have only very little understanding, why this works and I'll be glad if someone can shed more light on this.

Comment: A similar thing happens when sending a sigint (ctrl-c) to a ts-node application running via nodemon. To properly kill the application in that scenario, listen to the SIGINT signal, and then send the SIGKILL signal.

Answer (score 2):

You can try running this command.

`nodemon --signal SIGINT ./index.js`