# Nodemon says it restarted my server, but it does not

Tags: node.js, reload, babeljs, watch, nodemon

I'm using `nodemon` to restart my `node` `express` server when I change the sources. When I change anything, the `nodemon` correctly spots the changed file and claims to restart the server:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
```

However, when I interact with the server, I still got the old behavior (until I restart the server manually). I disabled `babel`'s cache by setting env variable `BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1` (which worked, no ~/.babel.json was created). Is there some other cache I should disable to get the correct behavior? Any idea, why is this happening?

node: 5.1.0

nodemon: 1.8.1

platform: ArchLinux

UPDATE: It's probably not cache issue. I noticed that after saving my file, `nodemon` does not kill the child process; the old `node` is still running (`nodemon` should kill the old process and start a new one, right?) Manually killing my script works without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

I found out, this is caused by `node-tika` and `node-java` modules. See my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35229999/1761457